Bayesian linear regression about finding the likelihood
Pick a single data point $(x,t)$ and calculate and plot the likelihood for this single data point across all $w$ in your parameter space $(w_0 \times w_1)$  (for a single data point it is a univariate case of the likelihood, see equation).
The equation they are refering to is:
$$p(t|X, w)  = \prod_{i=1}^{N} N \left( t_i | w^T x_i, \beta^{-1} \right) = M N \left( t | X_{\text{ext}} w, \beta^{-1} I \right)
$$
I have my vector space w0 and w1 and I have generated randmon points from earlier question. Anyways I don't really understand this, what is M? Is it the number of columns given that the matrix X_ext is NXM?
Also can I use the norm.pdf() function on python for this?
